# Firebase database, find the existing value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase databse of structure as shown below :

```
[unique key1]

        [key1]
            value1 : abc
            value2 : def

        [key2]
            value1 : xyz
            value2 : pqr
```

I know the unique key `unique key1` and i need to know whether there is any value `abc` in `value1` in this database. I have written the code as shown below, but it always return zero.

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(unique key1).orderByChild("value1").equalTo("abc").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
                      Toast.makeText(context, abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you assign the value of abc?

Answer (score 2):

You are really close. Instead of `orderByChild` you need `orderByValue` in this case, since you're actually looking for the child that has a specific value. So:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child(unique key1).orderByValue().equalTo("abc")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println("Found matching value in "+item.getKey());
            }
        }
```